# MVC 4 Cannot locate "Scripts" folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have problem with my project folder "Scripts". For some reason when I run the program in VS 2012, it gives me the exception:

> Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'c:\users\user\documents\visual
>   studio 2012\Projects\project1\project\Scripts'. Common reasons for
>   failure include:
>   - The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
>   - The filename is not an absolute path.
>   - The filename contains wildcard characters.
>   - The file specified is a directory.
>   - Access denied.

Cannot load the .js files in it. Why is that happening? (Just to mention that I tried restarting and clearing the Temp folder).

**Edit:**
This is the code that throws the exception.

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
```

Comment: Looks like whatever is throwing the error is looking for a file, and you're pointing it to a directory. Are you using bundles? What does the bundles file look like?

Comment: You sure your scripts folder is in the same director where your controller / model folders are? If so, make sure you have this in both your web.config `<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>`

Comment: Yes they are at the same folder. And I have in my web.config this namespace, but still the same problem..

Comment: Is says "Access Denied" - try running VS in administrator mode (right click the VS icon -> choose run as administrator).

Comment: Just tried it. No change. Same error.

Comment: Try starting a brand new project and see if it runs, then look at what if any changes you made that may be blowing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created new project with Basic template. It fixes the problem. (The previous project template was "Empty"). :)